# R group variable in skim(data)

Tags: r

when I use skimr::skim(data) I see that one variable is 'group variable' and statistics (n_missing, min, max and etc.) is given to each type of this group variable.
In my case this group variable is number of rooms (dataset is for rental prices and features of apartments).
Does anyone know how to get rid of this 'group variable' characteristics and to make this variable a normal variable?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the factor variable into numeric. For checking the levels of the factor variable, you need to run this.

```
levels(df$rooms)
```

If the groups are numbered like 1,2 and 3, you can directly convert it into numeric

```
data$rooms <- as.numeric(data$rooms)
```

If the levels of the factor variable are "Single", "Double", "Triple", etc., You need to convert the levels into numeric levels by running this.

```
levels(data$rooms) <- c(1, 2, 3) #Ensure that the numbers are in the same order of levels(df$rooms)
data$rooms <- as.numeric(data$rooms)
```

After this, you can run `skim(data)`

Comment: hi, thanks you for trying to help. df$rooms is initially in numeric format and it still a group variable.